# C# Api to Appcelerator app in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have made a very simple Web API in C# which does all the functionality required and have also made a simple User Interface in Appcelerator (Java Script). My task is to connect these two together so the app has the functionality of the API. I believe I must use JSON to communicate between C# and Java Script but I'm not sure how to do this.

Can anyone help or point me to the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own API implementation in javascript that talks to your restful service via http calls.

Also, I recommend taking a look at this project here: https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi which can save you a lot of time doing so.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction which will allow my Javascript app to communicate with the C# API? 
Thank You

Comment: read here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient about making http calls from your titanium app to your server. now what you should do is write calls to your API (I would wrap it up nicely for code reuse). Also, have a look at the github project I linked to above - with just a few settings you can have an already made api wrapper.

Comment: My API is currently running locally so doesn't have a URL. What would I put for the URL variable?

Comment: If you're testing from the device on the same network then you can put the ip address of your host machine. You can also check out services like http://www.noip.com/free which will give you a dns pointing to your machine (you will have to enable your server port in local machine firewall and maybe in your routers firewall if you want access from outside your network).

Answer (score 0):

The language in which your web API (service) is written is irrelevant to the question. You can use [Ti.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) to connect to any web service.

You just need to know what requests the API requires and how it responds. Most APIs nowadays use REST JSON, which means you request via an URL with optional body (for POST/PUT calls) and the response is in JSON format which you can parse using [JSON.parse](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Global.JSON-method-parse)